What does executing docker exec inside a subprocess change the output?
If I run the command docker exec -it stupefied_poitras bash -c 'time date', then I get the following output
Thu Sep 19 05:02:04 UTC 2024

real    0m0.000s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s

If I run the command A=$(docker exec -it stupefied_poitras bash -c 'time date') && echo $A, then I get
 sys 0m0.000ss02:09 UTC 2024

If I run the command A=$(docker exec -it stupefied_poitras bash -c 'time date' 1>&2) && echo $A, then I get
Thu Sep 19 05:14:59 UTC 2024

real    0m0.002s
user    0m0.001s
sys     0m0.000s

I'm fairly confused by the second output. Why is only the last line of stderr included and where does the carriage return come from (assuming that is the reason for the overwrite)?
Additionally, I'm also confused by 2 other behaviours:
This behaviour is only present if I use docker exec. That is,  A=$(bash -c 'time date') && echo $A doesn't exhibit it (although in that case the output of time is preceding the output of date). How come it is reversed?
If I redirect stderr to stdout (2>&1) in the third case, then I get the same messed up output as the second case. How come the the it matters whether I direct stdout to stderr or vice versa?
EDIT: I made a mistake in how to interpret the second case. What I see in the console is not the content of the variable rather than the content of stderr. Since A=$(docker exec -it bash bash -c 'time date' 1>&2) && echo '---' && echo $A yields
Thu Sep 19 05:30:32 UTC 2024

real    0m0.000s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
---


Try declare -p A instead of echo $A.

Perhaps the bash builtin command time produces different output, depending on whether fd 1 is connected to stdout or stderr. Strangel my bash man-page does not describe the command time at all, although bash itself reports it as builtin.
